# aggregate in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

[image: 1]

and need to aggregate like below

[image: 2]

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp2
SELECT item, Quantity, Seconds
SUM(Quantity) AS total_quantity,
--SUM(Seconds) AS total_seconds,
--SUM(Seconds)/3600 AS items_per_hour
INTO #tmp2
FROM #tmp1
GROUP BY item
```

Comment: So what is your question? What's wrong with `SUM`?

Comment: error message:#tmp1.quantity is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the groupby clause

Comment: The error is literally telling you to problem. `Quantity` is both *inside* and *outside* aggregate function.

Comment: @larnu got it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want the sun of a column you can directly invoke the same column in select

```
    SELECT item

    SUM(Quantity) AS total_quantity,
    --SUM(Seconds) AS total_seconds,
    --SUM(Seconds)/3600 AS items_per_hour
    INTO #tmp2
    FROM #tmp1
    GROUP BY item
```

Answer (score 0):

For aggregation you do not need `Quantity` and `Seconds`. Try the following

```
SELECT 
   item,
   SUM(Quantity) AS total_quantity,
   SUM(Seconds) AS total_seconds,
   SUM(Seconds)/3600 AS items_per_hour
FROM #tmp1
GROUP BY 
  item
```